# Exponentiation of non-negative measurable function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions from $X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) >0$ for all $x$.
Prove that $(f^g)(x) = f(x)^{g(x)}$ ($f$ to the $g$ power) is a measurable function.

I know that a function is measurable if and only if  the inverse image of $(a,\infty)$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}$. But I'm not sure how to use that definition here.

Comment: f^g>a implies g*ln(f)>lna. Since f is measure ln(f) is also measurable. So g * ln(f) is measurable.is this the right way to go ?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a > 0$, then
$$\{f^g > a\} = \{g \log(f) > \log(a)\} \in \mathcal{S}$$
since $g$ and $\log f$ are measurable functions.

Also, if $a \leq 0$, then $\{f^g  > a\} = X \in \mathcal{S}$

We conclude that $\{f^g > a\}\in \mathcal{S}$ for all $a \in \Bbb{R}$.
Hence, $f^g$ is measurable.